# Dojo IE DataGrid inline editing

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have enabled inline editing of cells in DataGrid and it is working fine all browsers except IE.

The problem is that after double clicking a cell and performing changed in values of cell, I have to double click on another cell within the grid. If I single/double click outside the grid, the cell which the user was editing still remains in edit mode.

I have overridden the onApplyCellEdit event of datagrid to capture changes and submit to server.

There is no javascript error in developer tools console of IE

Any ideas or pointers to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has also been added to the other linked question but also adding here for completeness.

Ok I've found the fix. It seems like it works perfectly. You need to register for the onBlur event of the grid and manually call save on your grid.

```
vGrid.onBlur = function(){
    var grid = dijit.byId('validation_grid');
    if (grid.edit.isEditing()){
        grid.edit.apply();
    }
};
```