# Not coming out of inline editing in Dojo DataGrid

Tags: internet-explorer, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dojo IE DataGrid inline editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355707/dojo-ie-datagrid-inline-editing)

The cells in the grid in the following jsfiddle are editable but I am :

**not able** to come out of the edit mode when I  double click on the cell, change the value, click **outside** the grid.

**able** to come out of the edit mode when I  double click on the cell, change the value, click **inside** the grid.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/keemor/xDUpp/11/

Can some please fix that jsfidddle for me.

Comment: I was just about to post the same problem. It is an IE issue. You'll notice that it works as expected in Firefox and Chrome. It is more noticeable in my example because it is using a select list. In this example Column 2 is the editable one. http://jsfiddle.net/nNZFh/3/

Comment: The problem is that `grid.doApplyCellEdit` is not being called in IE when the grid loses focus. I've tried and cannot figure out how to get this event to fire.

Comment: @Neil you are  right.                                                If we raise this is a bug on dojo website, what are the chances that it will be resolved in next release?

Comment: I don't know, but I need it fixed before that so a work around or something is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've found the fix. It seems like it works perfectly. You need to register for the onBlur event of the grid and manually call save on your grid.

```
vGrid.onBlur = function(){
    var grid = dijit.byId('validation_grid');
    if (grid.edit.isEditing()){
        grid.edit.apply();
    }
};
```